# Adding, updating and deleting subdocument nested under subdocument

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

Following is my JSON data structure.

```
{
    "id": "54e73250fc670bf2068e88c1",
    "name": "abc",
    "subCategory": [
        {
            "id": "54ec0c4ee4b036a9fa3767cd",
            "name": "pqr",
            "subCategory":[
                    {
                      "name":"abcd",
                       "subCategory":[
                          {
                           "name":"xyz"
                            "subCategory":[ 
                                    {
                                           ........
                                    }
                                  ]
                          }

               }
   ]

        },
        {
            "id": "54ec0c4ee4b036a9fa3767ce",
            "name": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "name": "abcde"
        },
        {
            "name": "abcde"
        },
        {
            "id": "54ec0c4be4b036a9fa3767ca",
            "name": "abcde"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting problem while doing add, update and delete operation using mongoDB and spring MVC.
I  did query as
1.Add Document under sub Document

```
public void addGrandChildCategory(subCategory category, String parentId) {
    List<subCategory> subCategory = null;
    if (category.getSubCategory() == null) {
        category.setSubCategory(subCategory);
    }
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("subCategory._id")
            .is(new ObjectId(parentId))), new Update().push(
            "subCategory.subCategory", category), subCategory.class);
}
```

2.update subDocument

```
public void updateSubCategory(String id, Integer index, String categoryName) {
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
            new Query(Criteria.where("subCategory[" + index + "].id").is(
                    new ObjectId(id))),
            new Update().set("subCategory.name", categoryName),
            subCategory.class);
}
```

3. For deleting, i had deleted document and a sub Document. Is the method remain Same for n levels of nesting.

My model classes Are:

1- Category

```
package com.cheasyy.cat;

import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

/**
 * Model class for category
 * 
 * @author Gaurav
 * 
 */
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility =     Visibility.ANY)
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Document(collection = "Category")
public class CategoryStructure {
private String id;



private String name;
private List<subCategory> subCategory;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<subCategory> getSubCategory() {
    return subCategory;
}

public void setSubCategory(List<subCategory> subCategory) {
    this.subCategory = subCategory;
}



}
```

2- SubCategory

```
package com.cheasyy.cat;

import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility =     Visibility.ANY)
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Document(collection = "Category")
/**
 * Model class for sub Category
 * @author Gaurav
 *
 */
public class subCategory
{
private String id=new ObjectId().toString();

private String name;

private List<subCategory> subCategory;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<subCategory> getSubCategory() {
    return subCategory;
}

public void setSubCategory(List<subCategory> subCategory) {
    this.subCategory = subCategory;
}




}
```

Comment: Have you tried this without the code straight in the mongoshell? That usually helps me figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: i have tried it, but not getting where i m doing mistake